# getting run time errors in android app

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, runtime-error

i m new to programming and android. i m making an android app for reading a binary file from sd card and plotting its content on 14 graphs. my code is 534 lines long so i can't post it here.  so,given below is the logcat that is displayed when i try to run the app. It asks for force close as soon as it starts. I m getting null pointer exception along with other errors. Please point me where am i going wrong. Thanks for ur time.

```
06-29 10:53:02.895: D/AndroidRuntime(12035): Shutting down VM
06-29 10:53:02.895: W/dalvikvm(12035): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught  exception (group=0x40015560)
06-29 10:53:02.915: E/AndroidRuntime(12035): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-29 10:53:02.915: E/AndroidRuntime(12035): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to   start activity ComponentInfo{debug.namespace/debug.namespace.DebugActivity}:     java.lang.NullPointerException
06-29 10:53:02.915: E/AndroidRuntime(12035):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
06-29 10:53:02.915: E/AndroidRuntime(12035):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
06-29 10:53:02.915: E/AndroidRuntime(12035):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
06-29 10:53:02.915: E/AndroidRuntime(12035):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
06-29 10:53:02.915: E/AndroidRuntime(12035):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-29 10:53:02.915: E/AndroidRuntime(12035):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-29 10:53:02.915: E/AndroidRuntime(12035):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
06-29 10:53:02.915: E/AndroidRuntime(12035):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-29 10:53:02.915: E/AndroidRuntime(12035):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-29 10:53:02.915: E/AndroidRuntime(12035):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
06-29 10:53:02.915: E/AndroidRuntime(12035):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
06-29 10:53:02.915: E/AndroidRuntime(12035):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-29 10:53:02.915: E/AndroidRuntime(12035): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-29 10:53:02.915: E/AndroidRuntime(12035):    at debug.namespace.DebugActivity.onCreate(DebugActivity.java:258)
06-29 10:53:02.915: E/AndroidRuntime(12035):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
06-29 10:53:02.915: E/AndroidRuntime(12035):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
06-29 10:53:02.915: E/AndroidRuntime(12035):    ... 11 more
06-29 10:53:05.995: I/Process(12035): Sending signal. PID: 12035 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Please provide DebugActivity as error it's line 258....

Comment: what's there in DebugActivity.java line number 258

Comment: seriesrenderer1.setColor(Color.BLUE); this is line no 258. It is a method in Achartengine, the library that i m using to plot the charts.

Answer (score 0):

then insert

```
Log.d("=====","===== seriesrenderer1="+seriesrenderer1);
```

before your line 258. I think it will turn out to be null.

If it is library code, you probably did not pass some parameters in the intent.
Anyway, find out where seriesrenderer1 comes from. Most likely, it is null because some parameter(s) have not been provided.